# git post-receive is not triggered

Tags: git, webserver, synchronization

I'm having trouble with updating web server root whenever git remote repository is pushed. The problem is as follows:

I made a file `update.php` that executes `git pull` from the remote repo, which it works (If I, after I pushed to the remote-repo, access http://www.mydomain.com/update.php through a web browser, the contents in the web server are up-to-date).

I made a file `.git/hooks/post-receive` in the remote-repo to access the `update.php` and checked if it works manually by executing it from the terminal (the contents in the web server are up-to-date again).

But `.git/hooks/post-receive` is not automatically triggered when i push commits from a local-repo to the remote-repo.

Isn't the `post-receive` supposed to be automatically called when remote repo is pushed? I'm dying to know what the problem is... I know already it's not related to the permission thing but I have tried all the permission-changing solutions on the web (and, of course, nothing worked).

#### My `post-receive`-script:

```
cd ..
env -i git reset --hard
```

---

Why is the `post-receive`-script not triggered automatically?

Comment: How do you push to your remote-repo? Which protocol do you use? I think I might have an answer, I'll investigate a bit more and post a new answer later on. :)

Comment: Well, I don't know the protocol or specific methods to push to remote repo. From my local repo, I just enter 'git push' in the terminal (I'm using Mac).

Comment: Okay - did you set up the remote-repository on your own, do you have somehow admin-access to your remote server?

Comment: Yes, I set up the remote repo on my own, and have two accounts in the server-'root' and 'myAccount' both of which belong to the 'sudo' and 'root' group.

Comment: Okay and which url did you use to connect to your repo? (f.e. "git://")

Comment: I've never used such url before, so I don't know about that. Instead, when I clone the remote git repo into my local directory, I used 'git clone myAccount@server-ip:/var/www/remoterepo.git'.

Comment: btw - might it be, that the first line of your recieve-script should be `cd ../..` to go back from the hooks-directory down into the repo-root?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, manual execution of post-receive works, which I think means the script itself contains nothing wrong. I tried a lot and figured out the problem is the script is not triggered automatically.

Comment: Hi @florianb, did you find any answer? I've tried to solve this, but still no proper answer found yet...

Comment: Hi @JoonhoJin, on the current informationbase I can't help you further. You could provide some information how you put the repo on the server and which steps you took to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`.git/hooks/post-receive`-hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is completely right.

I suggest you to check if the server-user has the filesystem-rights to execute it.

#### Checking execution rights

Log into your remote server and change into `<<your-repo>>/.git/hooks`, there you can invoke [`ls -l`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ls.1.html) to list all visible file in the "long" format. You should now see something like:

```
-rwxr-xr--   12 billythekid  unicorns      408 19 Mar  2013 post-receive
^               ^            ^                              ^
|               |            |                              |
|               + owner      + group                        + filename
|
+ file-type & permissions
```

The first character (`-`) tells us that were working with a file (and not with a `d`irectory or `l`ink) after that there are following three times the three possible permissions (`r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute) for the roles `owner`, `group` and `other`.

Now you have to assure that either the server-process is owner or part of the enlisted group and wether `owner` or `group` has execution rights. Or the execution-permissions for `other` is granted.

You may modify ownership with [`chown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) and modify the permissions with [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). You can read more about file permissions in this [Ubuntu community help-article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my web server, and the remote repo is in the same directory where the root directory of web server is (/var/www/project_name.git). Where and what should I check for the filesystem-rights to execute post-receive? Sorry if it's a too basic question, because I'm really new to this.

Comment: No worries, log into your remote, change to the hooks-directory and run `ls -la`. Follow this [tutorial](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/) to check the execution rights. I'll follow up with detailed instructions.

Comment: Hi, thankfully I have a little knowledge about the permissions so I had set everything in the hooks-directory to 777(rwxrwxrwx, for directories rwxrwsrwx), but nothing worked so far :( To the best of my knowledge, 777 should do everything though it's not the best option for further use. Is there anything I had to do more than this or Is my setting far from what I had to do?

Comment: Hi @JoonhoJin, how do you check/know if the script is not executed?

Comment: Could you please post the content of your `post-receive`-file? And you should consider doing some logging at the beginning: `date >> receive.log`

Comment: I put the contents of post-receive above(the --ADDED-- part of updated question). And thanks for the logging advice. I'll try that.

Comment: Well, I already knew the file permissions so you don't have to explain them. What I'd like to know is which ownership the directory (.git/hooks) should have to be executed by the server-process. It is set as 'root' now but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JoonhoJin - i'll remove the permissions-explanation. Usually it is enough, having the permissions of `others` temporarily set. I have another suggestion - how do you the repository serve? As long as you don't use any kind of "git-server" the hooks aren't called at all.

Comment: I'll investigate that assumption

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what 'how do you the repository serve?' means (poor english...). Do you want to know how I set up the remote repo? Please ask me more specifically then I'll answer properly, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry - no native speaker, too.. :) The execution may depend on how you access the repo from outside. I'm currently trying to find out what is going to trigger the hooks, since the remote-git must trigger it in any way.